# FireBird, простой триггер на удаление не работает

Tags: firebird, interbase, триггер

Использую FireBird 2.5.4. и ibexpert
Посмотрел как люди делают (и видно чего-то недопонял), и решил тоже написать триггер на запрет удаления записи (AFTERDELETE)
Можно ли так писать?:
(вылетают такие 2 ошибки)

```
if (old.COUNT_LINK > 0) then
  begin
    PRINT 'Запись имеет ссылку' //ошибка SQL error code = -104. Token unknown - line 8, column 11. "Запись имеет ссылку".
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION // SQL error code = -104. Token unknown - line 9, column 5. ROLLBACK.
  end;
```

Что тут не так?
Или это не приемлемо в sql?

Answer (score 1):

Если я только правильно понял, вы хотите запретить удаление родительской записи, если имеется дочерняя. Ну уж тогда не AFTER, а BEFORE. Но запрет этот следует делать при создании таблицы не триггером, а специальной опцией FireBird, запрещающей каскадное удаление. Кажется так.

Comment: Нет, каскадное, наверно не получиться, т.к. в поле "COUNT_LINK", содержится только количество дочерних записей, ссылающихся на родительскую

Comment: А зачем это? Зачем Вы заменяете запрос полем? Это поле еще и поддерживать надо!

Comment: Я наверное не совсем Вас понял, я не хотел заменять запрос полем.   Просто я не хочу удалять запись, есле значение в поле больше "0", **при этом выдавая соответствующее сообщение**. Можно конечно это все проворачивать на стороне клиента, но я бы всетаки хотел это делать с помощью сервера

Comment: Поле "COUNT_LINK" заменяет собою запрос.

Comment: Поле "COUNT_LINK" - это числовое поле, и там просто находится количество ссылок

Comment: И я о том же. Зачем оно Вам понадобилось?

Comment: У меня есть таблица слов, в этой таблице, встречаются слова синонимы, Когда я с какого-то слова делаю ссылку на синоним, то в поле "COUNT_LINK", производится инкремент на один.
Также у слов есть поле "ID_Synonym", в котором через запятую хранится список ID на синонимы. Знаю что лучше было бы создать еще таблицу с сылками, но таблица из трех полей...

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23864/discussion-between-konstantin78-and-builderc).

Answer (score 1):

Забудьте о методах из MS SQL или откуда вы взяли свой код.

```
create exception EHasLink 'Запись имеет ссылку';

create or alter trigger docum_bi for docum
active before delete
as
begin
if (old.COUNT_LINK > 0) then
  exception EHasLink;
end;
```